# calculating the eigenvector from a complex eigenvalue in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, complex-numbers, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I am trying to calculate the eigenvector of a 4x4 matrix in opencv.
For this I first calculate the eigenvalue according to this formula:

```
Det( A - lambda * identity matrix ) = 0
```

From [wiki on eigenvalues and eigenvectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Matrices).
After solving this, it gives me 4 eigenvalues that look something like this:

```
0.37789 + 1.91687i
0.37789 - 1.91687i
0.412312 + 1.87453i
0.412312 - 1.87453i
```

From these 4 eigenvalues I take the highest value and I want use that with this formula:

```
( A - lambda * identity matrix ) v = 0
```

I tried to use my original matrix A with the opencv function "eigen()", but this doesn't give me the results I am looking for.
I also tried to use RREF (reduced row echelon form), however I don't know how to do this with complex eigenvalues.

**So my question is, how would you calculate this eigenvector?**

I plugged my data in to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20eigenvector&a=*C.solve%20eigenvector-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=%7B%7B0.40%20-%20%28%200.41%20%2B%201.87i%20%29%2C1.90%2C0.01%2C-0.16%7D%2C%7B-1.90%2C0.40%20-%20%28%200.41%20%2B%201.87i%20%29%2C0.16%2C0.01%7D%2C%7B0.01%2C0.16%2C0.40%20-%20%28%200.41%20%2B%201.87i%20%29%2C-1.90%7D%2C%7B-0.16%2C0.01%2C1.90%2C0.40%20-%20%28%200.41%20%2B%201.87i%20%29%7D%7D&f=Eigenvector.eigvecmatrix_%7B%7B0.40%20-%20%28%200.41%20%2B%201.87i%20%29%2C1.90%2C0.01%2C-0.16%7D%2C%7B-1.90%2C0.40%20-%20%28%200.41%20%2B%201.87i%20%29%2C0.16%2C0.01%7D%2C%7B0.01%2C0.16%2C0.40%20-%20%28%200.41%20%2B%201.87i%20%29%2C-1.90%7D%2C%7B-0.16%2C0.01%2C1.90%2C0.40%20-%20%28%200.41%20%2B%201.87i%20%29%7D%7D) to see what my results should be.

Comment: "doesn't give me the results I am looking for", what do you mean by this? what results do you get? Did you try do solve the equation yourself, or only via `eigen()`?

Comment: If you only need the highest eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector, using a [power iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) might be an option

Comment: @tobi303 eigen() will always return:
 [-0.50, -0.50, -0.50, 0.50;
 0.50, 0.50, -0.50, 0.50;
 -0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50;
 -0.50, 0.50, -0.50, -0.50]
only the +/- will be different.

I will check the power iteration and see if this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the problem using the '[ComplexEigenSolver](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ComplexEigenSolver.html)' from the [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

```
//create a multichannel matrix
Mat a_com = Mat::zeros(4,4,CV_32FC2);
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<4; j++)
    {
        a_com.at<Vec2f>(i,j)[0] = a.at<double>(i,j);
        a_com.at<Vec2f>(i,j)[1] = 0;
    }
}

MatrixXcf eigenA;
cv2eigen(a_com,eigenA); //convert OpenCV to Eigen
ComplexEigenSolver<MatrixXcf> ces;
ces.compute(eigenA);
cout << "The eigenvalues of A are:\n" << ces.eigenvalues() << endl;
cout << "The matrix of eigenvectors, V, is:\n" << ces.eigenvectors() << endl;
```

This gives me the following output (which is more or less what I was looking for):

```
The eigenvalues of A are:
(0.3951,-1.89571)
(0.3951,1.89571)
(0.3951,1.89571)
(0.3951,-1.89571)
The matrix of eigenvectors, V, is:
(-0.704546,0)            (-5.65862e-009,-0.704546)     (-0.064798,-0.0225427)      (0.0167534,0.0455606)
(-2.22328e-008,0.707107)   (0.707107,-1.65536e-008)    (0.0206999,-0.00474562)    (-0.0145628,-0.0148895)
(-6.07644e-011,0.0019326) (0.00193259,-4.52426e-011)   (-0.706729,6.83797e-005)    (-0.000121153,0.706757)
(-1.88954e-009,0.0600963)  (0.0600963,-1.40687e-009)      (0.00200449,0.703827)     (-0.70548,-0.00151068)
```

Answer (score 1):

Opencv already has function for calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors, `cv::eigen()`. I advise using it instead of writing the algorithm yourself.

Here is good [blog](http://bytefish.de/blog/eigenvalues_in_opencv/) that explains how to do this in c, c++ and python.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but as you could have read cv::eigen() doesn't give me the answer that I am looking for since it always returns roughly the same vectors with different matrices.